# Determine the encoding from byte array

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, byte, arrays

I was wondering if there's any solution to get the encoding of a byte array? I have an application which accepts one parameter and returns an array of bytes, suppose I have this array of bytes:

```
ED 3F 3F 3F ED 15 3F 3F
```

And also I know that it's the byte array of string `سلام`, but I don't know how that application encoded the string and I need to know which ending is the application uses for converting the string to byte array.

Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse-Engineering the application which is encoding the string to byte array, to find out the encoding scheme is the only solution,I can think of (if that is an option).

Generic method for doing such, is highly unrealistic in my opinion.